# python 3 self class dict

Tags: python, methods, dictionary

I am trying to create my own class of dictionary in python 3 which has a field of dict variable and setitem and getitem methods. Though, it doesnt work for some reason. Tried to look around but couldn't find the answer.

```
class myDictionary:
    def __init(self):
        self.myDic={}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.myDic[key]=value
```

I'm getting:

```
'myDictionary' object has no attribute 'myDic'
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: That should be `__init__`, not `__init`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the trailing underscores on `__init__()`, try the following:

```
class myDictionary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myDic={}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.myDic[key]=value
```

Answer (score 1):

You've a typo within your `__init__` method. Change it:

```
class myDictionary:
   def __init__(self):
      self.myDic={}

   def __setitem__(self, key, value):
      self.myDic[key]=valu
```

Comment: Owww dude thanks. this is the kind of mistakes you never sees... thanks alot. what a fool question lol.